# Receiving 404 "Missing Resource" error for Controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.Net MVC Design pattern and when adding a controller to my application I'm receiving the below error. I added the controller called EmailMeController.cs in the Controllers folder and everything builds correctly. I created a link to /EmailMe/ but that doesn't work. I've added another controller previously to the same site with no problems. Here's a link to my controller: http://pastebin.com/m373fae3b

Hopefully you guys can help. I certainly appreciate it.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /EmailMe

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only Index action in the controller is [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

You need an Index action for Get:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have it as a POST method. You need an action for GET.

Answer (score 0):

Add another ActionMethod with the [HTTPGet] annotation of the same name (MVC2).

After that, and you still get the 404, check that you add the asp.net dll for a wild card handler in your web app if you are using Windows server 2003 or earlier.  If you are using 2008, make sure you actually have an application defined.  I got hung on those too before.

Yet another thing to check is the Routes:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

If your method includes parameters other than id, it may not match.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I removed default Views for the HomeController and ValueController which resulted in this problem. After adding all those views and controllers that comes as default when we create application i got rid of the error. Make sure you have those default views and controllers. This answer may help.